# wffm 8.1 captcha field validation not working, but fine for other fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.1

On WFFM submit action validation is working for all the fields except reCaptcha field, though the captcha is verified but the validation message still shows the "field is mandatory" on submit as well as focus out event, and this needs to be fixed on jquery.validate.js or jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js as all our projects are using, please help

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue require two workaround steps:

1. Uncheck the required checkbox for the captcha field noticing that the form will still validate this field.
2. Hide the required functionality for the captcha field navigate to the /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Complex/Captcha item and uncheck the required option - this will remove possibility to mark captcha as required in the Form Designer.

Source: http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/wffm-captcha-required-field-issue_58.html